# What are the various scientific proofs that Ramayana and Mahabharata describe real events in history and are not just mythical tales?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana

I am really interested in understanding that where did all the ultramodern concepts like 'Brahmastra' (today's nukes) or the vimanas (today's aeroplane and space shuttles) etc, which were literally ages ahead of those times suddenly vanish into thin air. I don't intend to delve into all the god and reincarnation debate but more interested in the knowledge and know-how bit that is supposedly described during those times.